# gsub out "~$" from temporary file name

Tags: r

In a file path given as a character string how are you able to replace the special characters ~$ from a temporary file path (created when someone is in an excel document). I've tried to escape them with \ with no luck. I'm sure it's not complicated but I cant figure it out. Thanks!

in the below example I would like it to say "test string here" after the gsub.

```
x <- "~$test string here"
gsub("[:punct:]","",x)
[1] "~$es srig here"
```

Comment: add an extra `[` `gsub("[[:punct:]]","",x)`

Comment: That Worked thanks!

Comment: alternatively you can escape `~` and `$` this way: `sub("\\~\\$", "", x)`